# httplib does not work in script

Tags: python, httplib

On loading `httplib` in terminal returns no error, but when I load the library in a script, I got this error:

```
File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
import httplib
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 74, in <module>
from urlparse import urlsplit
File "/home/nakisa/Desktop/testURL/urlparse.py", line 2, in <module>
from tld import get_tld
File "/home/nakisa/Desktop/testURL/src/tld/src/tld/__init__.py",  
line    9, in <module>
from tld.utils import get_tld, get_tld_names, update_tld_names, Result
File "/home/nakisa/Desktop/testURL/src/tld/src/tld/utils.py", line 
 13, in <module>
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
ImportError: cannot import name urlparse
```

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your script.

Comment: I got this error with a single line script, only "import httplib"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file

```
/home/nakisa/Desktop/testURL/urlparse.py
```

which is shadowing the built-in Python library [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) that is required by `httplib`.

Rename your file.

**Edit:**

This is what is happening on your machine.

```
$ cat so.py
import httplib
$ cat urlparse.py
# this is empty
$ python2.7 so.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 1, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 74, in <module>
    from urlparse import urlsplit
ImportError: cannot import name urlsplit
```

**Edit 2:**

Rename your file `urlparse.py` to something else like `myurlparse.py`. Then you can import `httplib`.